# No es posible addEventListener en propiedad null

Tags: javascript

Estoy tratando de agregar un evento `click` pero no me funciona, me dice no es posible `addEventListener` a una propiedad null, pero el nombre del botón  es el mismo al que le estoy añadiendo el evento.

Si desde el botón coloco `onclick="saludar()"` ahí si se ejecuta y, según veo comentarios, el script se ubica antes de cerrar el `body` pero no me funciona no lo reconoce pero solo con agregar evento, por que suele suceder eso, por que en si es el mismo id del nombre el que coloco en la  el selector tengo algo asi:

Un botón con `id=boton_r`  y en js hago esto

```
let bot=document.getElementById("boton_r";   bot.addEventListener("click",function (){
    Alert("HOLA");
})
```

pero no me funciona  con el `add` y con `onclick` desde `html` si, y lo extraño es que si creo un nuevo proyecto con un solo archivo `html` y antes de cerrar `body` hago el script y agrego el evento si funciona. ¿Saben que podría hacer en este caso?

Comment: ¿Puedes compartir tu código? Te invito a leer [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Por lo que veo el problema es dónde colocas el js, si lo colocas en el `head`, los elementos del dom seguramente no estén cargados en el momento en que se ejecuta el código y por eso sale `null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto pasa porque el DOM aun no esta cargado, el evento que estas asignando a un elemento de tu DOM aun no existe y es por eso que no contiene ese evento.

Puedes con jquery usar `$(document).ready()` o si lo estas haciendo con puro JS puedes ocupar domready.js

Comment: Hola @LuisLopezMoreno, bienvenid@ a [es.so] te sugiero completar el [tour] para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [answer] para que tus respuestas sean de calidad.

Comment: Hola  amigo, lo hice con jquery ya no me sale el error pero tampoco ejecuta la funcion